# git pull alternates between two messages, one telling me about origin/HEAD (forced update) and one telling me about origin/master

Tags: git

I thought cloning a fresh copy of my repository would solve this issue but apparently I was wrong:

```
alex@kallobombus:~/src$ git clone git@github.com:kensanata/face.git
Cloning into 'face'...
remote: Counting objects: 484, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (457/457), done.
remote: Total 484 (delta 82), reused 423 (delta 24), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (484/484), 1.40 MiB | 1.57 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (82/82), done.
alex@kallobombus:~/src$ cd face
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
From github.com:kensanata/face
 + d88ddb7...1d9f4b3 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
Already up-to-date.
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
From github.com:kensanata/face
   1d9f4b3..d88ddb7  master     -> origin/master
Already up-to-date.
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
From github.com:kensanata/face
 + d88ddb7...1d9f4b3 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
Already up-to-date.
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$
```

When I look at my log, everything seems to be OK:

```
alex@Megabombus:~/src/face (master %=)$ git log | head -n 2
commit d88ddb71534506b178cebd9c552441e0968fe590
Author: Alex Schroeder <alex@gnu.org>
```

On a different machine, I don't seem to have this problem:

```
alex@Megabombus:~/src/face (master %=)$ git log | head -n 2
commit d88ddb71534506b178cebd9c552441e0968fe590
Author: Alex Schroeder <alex@gnu.org>
alex@Megabombus:~/src/face (master %=)$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
alex@Megabombus:~/src/face (master %=)$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
alex@Megabombus:~/src/face (master %=)$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

What's wrong on the first machine, kallobombus?

The result is that I always have to *pull twice*.

```
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 152, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (136/136), done.
remote: Total 152 (delta 26), reused 142 (delta 16), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (152/152), 285.01 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26), completed with 4 local objects.
From github.com:kensanata/face
   59f3bf1..978f6ca  master     -> origin/master
error: Ref refs/remotes/origin/master is at 978f6ca9912904c82274e5f91bddec3fb98882ff but expected 59f3bf1ee9703d50291703395920a3860b5e389a
 ! 59f3bf1...1d9f4b3 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (unable to update local ref)
make: *** [pull-face] Error 1
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
From github.com:kensanata/face
 + 978f6ca...1d9f4b3 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
Updating 59f3bf1..978f6ca
Fast-forward
 README.md                                     |  112 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----
 ...
```

Comment: Did you compare your `git config --list` on both machines if the pull settings differ?

Comment: @TeXter I did not, but when I checked just now, `git config --list|grep pull` had no output on both machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue once, that was caused by someone creating a branch literally named `HEAD` in the remote repository (and it was reproducible on all machines using that remote repo). And it seems, that is also your case:

```
$ git ls-remote 'https://github.com/kensanata/face.git'
d569da73560ce85fd870f7673b01f2385d55427f    HEAD
1d9f4b3769e2959e3033d4ff286f86851c34ef0c    refs/heads/HEAD     <- the problem
d569da73560ce85fd870f7673b01f2385d55427f    refs/heads/master
```

Maybe older versions of git handle this situation differently, but updating git will not fix this completely, you need to remove that branch:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/HEAD
```

Comment: Indeed, with this, I was able to downgrade my git and it worked! Thank you very much. As I'm the only one working on this repo I wonder how I managed to do this. I certainly never intended to do this.

Comment: I would have never been able to figure this one out in a million years. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was an old git version! The server where git had been misbehaving uses Debian Wheezy, ie. Debian 7.

```
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4
```

Make sure you have backports installed:

```
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ grep backport /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

So I updated and upgraded, and no more issues!

```
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install git
...
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
alex@kallobombus:~/src/face$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```